# sed with replacement part given as input from command line

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I am trying to pass command line argument as the replacement part to sed command. But $1 doesn't work for me.

For example I unsuccesfully tried

```
function changeversion() {
    sed -i 's/[0-9]\+/$1/g' file.xml;
}
```

which only replaced all numbers in file with '$1' text.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to put the expression in double qoutes to get variable substitution

```
function changeversion() {
   sed -i "s/[0-9]\+/$1/g" file.xml;
}
```

Comment: Great, now it does exactly what I needed. Thanks!